# Restsharp - The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: restsharp

I have an app that uses Restsharp to get data from third parties.

After a few days running, doing roughly 250 queries per hour, all queries will fail with this:

```
The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

Doing the same query with *curl* works properly and is happening with a variety of endpoints.

Restarting the app cures the problem, until next time.

This is the code:

```
    var Client = new RestClient("http://...");
    var Request = new RestRequest("...", Method.GET);
    Request.AddHeader("X-auth-Token", KEY);
    Request.AddQueryParameter("timeFrame", TimeFrame);

    // execute the query
    var Response = Client.Execute(Request);
    if (Response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Logging.Error($"{FeedId()} - Failed to get {Response.ResponseUri}, error is {Response.StatusCode} : {Response.ErrorMessage}");
        return false;
    }
```

This method is called from multiple threads.

Comment: Where do you dispose your request and client?

Comment: I don't do anything specific, I left them expire by getting out of context; is it possible that I run out of sockets by doing requests faster than the garbage collector will free the resources?

Comment: I have read that default socket lifetime in HttpClient is very long. I am not sure about WebRequest but from what I have read about `HttpWebResponse.Close`, it says "allow to reuse connection", which means that the connection is being kept open. I am planning to move RestSharp to use HttpClient, reusing a pool of clients.

Comment: Check this https://venkateshnarayanan.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/httpwebrequest-reuse-of-tcp-connections/. There was a PR to support connection groups in RestSharp https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/1027. The guy didn't bother to complete the work. If you think it can solve your issue - I can finish it rather quickly and release an alpha for you to try.

Comment: I think connection groups would be the way to go; I can definitely try the alpha when you have it

Comment: May be you can also try this? http://byterot.blogspot.no/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html

Comment: The latest preview implements the `ConnectionGroupName` on `IRestClient` https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/106.2.0-alpha0032